# Splitting UK Postcodes by matching to their outcode

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have been given a list of UK postcodes, with the following format L15TG or TS14TGU.

I need to be able to match these postcodes to a list of postcodes I have stored in the database, however, my list are only UK outcodes, so L15TG is just L1 and TS14TGU is just TS14.

So I need to match the records and return the part of the string that matches i.e take L1 from L15TG.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: sorry edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so we have a table named [BadCodes]

```
BadCode
-------
L15TG  
TS14TGU
```

and a table named [OutCodes]

```
OutCode
-------
L1     
TS14
```

I would add two `Text` fields to the [BadCodes] table: [OuterCode] and [InnerCode]

Then I would use the following VBA code to populate [BadCodes].[OuterCode]

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub PopulateOuterCodes()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rstOutCodes As DAO.Recordset
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("", _
            "PARAMETERS prmOuterCode TEXT(255), prmLike TEXT(255);" & _
            "UPDATE BadCodes SET OuterCode=[prmOuterCode] " & _
            "WHERE BadCode LIKE [prmLike] AND OuterCode IS NULL")
    Set rstOutCodes = cdb.OpenRecordset( _
            "SELECT OutCode FROM OutCodes " & _
            "ORDER BY Len(OutCode) DESC, OutCode", _
            dbOpenSnapshot)
    Do Until rstOutCodes.EOF
        qdf!prmOuterCode = rstOutCodes!OutCode
        qdf!prmLike = rstOutCodes!OutCode & "*"
        qdf.Execute
        rstOutCodes.MoveNext
    Loop
    rstOutCodes.Close
    Set rstOutCodes = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

After running that VBA code my [BadCodes] table would look like

```
BadCode  OuterCode  InnerCode
-------  ---------  ---------
L15TG    L1                  
TS14TGU  TS14
```

Then I could populate [BadCodes].[InnerCode] with the query

```sql
UPDATE BadCodes
SET InnerCode = Replace(BadCode,OuterCode,"",1,1)
```

and my [BadCodes] table would now look like

```
BadCode  OuterCode  InnerCode
-------  ---------  ---------
L15TG    L1         5TG      
TS14TGU  TS14       TGU
```